# On upgrading to phonegap 2.9.0 my app is not communicating with my web service through internet

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, dreamweaver, phonegap-build

In my app I am doing an ajax "post" request. This was returning me the data on building my .apk file using phonegap version 2.2.0. However on upgrading to version 2.9.0 it stopped working. It returns only "Success = " with no data.

I referred different articles on web but non helped.

```
$.post(baseURL+'/getcontent.jsp',
{
    struser:"",
    password:"",
    alias:"Industry",
    parameters:"0",
    retrieved:0,
    retrieve:20,
    offset:0
},
function(data,status){
    alert(status + " = " + data);
});
```

Can someone please suggest me where am i going wrong?
I do not have any AndroidManifest.xml file. Everything is controlled through config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.hahaha.xyz"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>Test App</name>

    <description>
        This app is developed by a first timer into app development.
    </description>

    <author href="http://hahaha.com" email="xyz@gmail.com">
        Test
    </author>

    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="8" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="18" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="10000"/>

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="images/icon36.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon48.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon72.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon96.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/screen.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

</widget>
```

I might be completely wrong on my judgement of phonegap version issue.

Just want someone to have an open view on this case. Any kind of help or hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After wasting couple of days on this issue, now I have reduced the phonegap version to 2.5.0 and it works like a charm. Still not sure why it failed on version 2.9.0, but for now I move on.

Cheers

Comment: Did you add the server to your whitelist? 

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide 

The whitelist may not have been working correctly on 2.9. 

Also, you weren't seeing anything in the logs? (logcat and web console?)